# Easy way to add a context action to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to add a very simple action to the context menu of Eclipse: clicking with right button over a folder object, this action should call an external tool (configured in the "External Tools") using the path of the folder as the only parameter.

I've found a [tutorial on how to add a context menu](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html), but it's more complex than what I need -- I don't really want to create a plugin, I don't even want to create classes to do what I want. My only purpose is to call an external tool.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to extend Eclipse with functionality such as editing context menu's, the only way to go is by writing a plug-in. However, this can be very light-weight and targeted to your needs, so the tutorial you found might be a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [StartExplorer](http://basti1302.github.com/startexplorer/). It's very handy. It's the equivalent of the IntelliJ "Neighborhood" plugin.

It comes with the basics of explore, command shell, open, and copy path for Windows, Mac and Linux. It also supports [custom commands](http://basti1302.github.com/startexplorer/help/05_custom_commands.html). And can be installed through a normal Eclipse repository.